# Select rows based on an array of values and join data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a MySQL database of **contacts** with three tables.

1. person
2. personContact
3. personDetails

Each contact shares a primary key called '**ID**'

The personContact table contains a value called '**personZip**' which happens to be their mailing address zip code.

I'd like to write a SQL query that will give me all the contact data for each person in a specific array of zip codes.

I've written a simple statement to perform an inner join on 2 of the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM `personContact`
INNER JOIN person
ON personContact.ID=person.ID
```

I've written a statement to select only the zip codes I need:

```
SELECT * FROM 'personContact'
WHERE personContact.personZip=12564 
OR personContact.personZip=12563 
OR personContact.personZip=12522 
OR personContact.personZip=12590
OR personContact.personZip=12594
OR personContact.personZip=12533
OR personContact.personZip=12570
OR personContact.personZip=12589
OR personContact.personZip=10509
```

I'm not sure how to perform two joins, to merge all columns from all three tables.

I'm not sure how to write the query to accommodate both the selection of zip codes and the JOINS.

MySQL errors are not helping me move in the right direction.

Comment: Why don't use `IN` clause instead?

Comment: I posted exactly what you asked for right from the start.  Have you even tried it?

Comment: @dbagley giving it a shot now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join all three tables and return all columns while filtering by zip code:

```
SELECT person.*, personContact.*, personDetails.*
FROM person
INNER JOIN personContact ON personContact.ID = person.ID
INNER JOIN personDetails ON personDetails.ID = person.ID
WHERE personContact.personZip = 12564
    OR personContact.personZip = 12563
    OR personContact.personZip = 12522
    OR personContact.personZip = 12590
    OR personContact.personZip = 12594
    OR personContact.personZip = 12533
    OR personContact.personZip = 12570
    OR personContact.personZip = 12589
    OR personContact.personZip = 10509
```

---

**EDIT**: Multiple `OR` statements can be replaced using `IN` as others have suggested

`WHERE personContact.personZip IN (12564, 12563, 12522, 12590 ...)`

Comment: Use `IN` would be more efficient in this case. `select *` would return all joined tables without describe them one by one.

Comment: I would probably also alias the tables, but I left it in the format presented in the question.

Comment: Any particular reason this query would take a very long time?

Comment: If you are comparing the run time to the other answer keep in mind that an additional table was added and more zip codes are being checked.  Otherwise, there could be various factors such as number of rows, table index, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Use `in` which is equivalent to `or`.

```
SELECT pc.* --select columns from the other tables as needed. 
 FROM 
`personContact` pc 
INNER JOIN person p ON pc.ID = p.ID
INNER JOIN personDetails pd on pd.ID = p.ID
where pc.personzip in (12563, 12522, 10509) -- add more zips as needed
```

Comment: `pc.zip` is throwing unknown column error. Not sure what .zip is.

Comment: it should have been `personzip`. modified the query

Comment: While this might work, I'm not sure what's happening here.

pc.* does...what?

Comment: pc.* returns all columns from the personContact table only

Comment: This just filters zip codes and returns columns from personContact table only. 

Not seeing columns from other two tables joined.

Comment: you should select the columns as needed from the other tables.